# Android Studio Bumblebee breaks build.gradle.kts

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-bumblebee

I recently upgraded to android studio bumblebee and all my `.kts` files are not getting picked up by the ide when using the embedded jdk.  The project still builds fine but I cannot properly edit these files since the ide is not recognizing them.
[image: build.gradle.kts]

[image: ide version]

If I switch the jdk version to 1.8 then everything works fine but I would like to use java 11 since that's what android studio recommends.

This is what my buildSrc looks like

[image: buildSrc]

Is this a known issue with android studio bumblebee and embedded jre or am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you included the kotlin-dsl plugin and created buildSrc folder ?

Comment: The AGP (Android Gradle Plugin) supports kotlin dsl.  Yes, I have a buildSrc folder.  For context, this project worked fine in Android Studio Arctic Fox (the previous version of the android studio).  I'm only seeing this issue with bumblebee but haven't been able to find an official issue for it.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the contents of buildSrc gradle file.  The `kotlin-dsl` plugin is there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213131387) deleting

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudioPreview20XX.X/options/jdk.table.xml
```

file fixes this issue

Comment: Thanks! I had the same issue after upgrading to Android Studio Dolphin and this workaround works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the content of the build.gradle.kts(buildSrc) with the following .The following code is working for me in my current multi-module project :

```
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.`kotlin-dsl`
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately, it doesn't make any difference.  Do you have the same setup? Android studio bumblebee using integrated jre ?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same setup. I have created a **buildSrc** Module within my project and within that I have the above file and the rest needed for enabling kts are generated by Android Studio .

Comment: If you hover over the error what does it say ?

Comment: This is the error message: "Cannot access 'java.lang.Comparable' which is a supertype of 'org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.KotlinBuildScript'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies"

Comment: The main thing is that it fixes the error if I change the gradle jdk to 1.8